# Beginner parsing with jq - Cannot index array with string

Tags: json, bash, shell, api, jq

Here is a snippet of the output when I do a basic jq, what I want to get is the data of the partitions.

```
jq .



[
 {
"partitions": [
  "name@website
],
"os_pid": "20458",
"fd_used": 20,
"fd_total": 1024,
"sockets_used": 2,
"sockets_total": 829,
"mem_used": 41128152,
```

When I do **jq '.partitions'** I get 
    Cannot index array with string "partitions" - Any thoughts as to why that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array, where each element has a `partitions` field. You ask to get "partitions", but you don't say from which element or elements in the array.

Here's a complete, self-contained file:

```
[
  {
    "partitions": [ "name@website" ]
  },
  {
    "partitions": [ "more" ]
  }
]
```

Your expression produces the error you say:

```
$ jq '.partitions' file
jq: error (at file:8): Cannot index array with string "partitions"
```

You can get "partitions" for the first element:

```
$ jq '.[0].partitions' file
[
  "name@website"
]
```

Or for each elements:

```
$ jq '.[].partitions' file
[
  "name@website"
]
[
  "more"
]
```

Or join all the partitions from each element into one list:

```
$ jq 'map(.partitions) | add' file
[
  "name@website",
  "more"
]
```